# Context Components in React 16.3 are invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the new Context components in React 16.3.1. I'm running a pretty straightforward example:

```
const TestContext = React.createContext();

export default class Test extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <TestContext.Provider value="abc">
        <TestContext.Consumer>
          {value => (
            <div>{value}</div>
          )}
        </TestContext.Consumer>
      </TestContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

However the code won't render, instead producing this error:

`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

It seems that both the Provider and Consumer components aren't valid components and can't be rendered by React.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out!

I updated React to 16.3.1, but didn't update ReactDOM.

Running `npm uninstall -s react-dom && npm i -s react-dom` updated it to 16.3.1 and fixed the issue.

Side note, I wouldn't have expected the new Context API to be dependent on ReactDOM.

Comment: I wrote about why this happens https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do/

Answer (score 0):

For your current situation you must return a react element in the `TestContext.Consumer`.

> **The Provider component** is used higher in the tree and **accepts a prop
>   called value** (which can be anything).
>
> **The Consumer component** is used
>   anywhere below the provider in the tree and accepts a prop called
>   “children” which must be a function that accepts the value and **must
>   return a react element (JSX).**

Make sure you render `<Test />` and not `<TestContext />`and you must be on react and react dom 16.3.1.

```
const TestContext = React.createContext();

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TestContext.Provider value="abc">
        <TestContext.Consumer>{value => <div>{value}</div>}</TestContext.Consumer>
      </TestContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

An example of how to do it with `this.props.children`

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const TestContext = React.createContext();

class TContext extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "abc"
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TestContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </TestContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TContext>
        <TestContext.Consumer>
          {context => <div>{context.state.value}</div>}
        </TestContext.Consumer>
      </TContext>
    );
  }
}

render(<Child />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Good catch on returning an element, I've updated my question to add a <div> tag. However, I'm still getting the same "Element type is invalid" error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjo22rvmn8 this works are you on 16.3.1? Show me where you render <Test />

Comment: Ah got it! I updated react to 16.3.1, but not react-dom. Updating react-dom fixed it. Thanks @omar!